# Gridster is not initialize with typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, gridster

I made simple working demo using Angularjs + typescript..I am trying to load gridster but gridster is not working.

Comment: What is error? show some code!

Comment: Provide what you've try so far.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to load gridster but gridster is not working.

You will need to setup:

- jquery
- gridster (the javascript)

Then you will need to get definitions for both `typings install dt~jquery` `typings install dt~gridster`